# Match everything except certain strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write python script to match a regex that can include everything which has two `-` and one `.` but I also want to exclude two strings from it. They are `NIST-Privacy-v1.1` and `NIST-CSF-v1.1`

Here is my sample data:

```
NIST-Privacy-v1.1
NIST-CSF-v1.1
AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.10
SOC-2-CC6.8
NIST-800-53rev5
NIST-800-53rev5-CM-3(1)
NIST-800-53rev5-AU-12(4)
SOC-2-CC6.1
NISTPrivacyFramework-v1.0
NISTPrivacyFramework-v1.0-PR.AC-P1
NIST-800-53rev5-AC-1
NIST-800-53rev5-IA-1
```

I started with a very simple regex which does the job of matching what I need but doesn't exclude the two strings. Can you help me identify the exclusion part.

regex:
`.*-.*-.*[.|\-].*`

Desired output:

```
AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.10
SOC-2-CC6.8
NIST-800-53rev5-CM-3(1)
NIST-800-53rev5-AU-12(4)
SOC-2-CC6.1
NISTPrivacyFramework-v1.0-PR.AC-P1
NIST-800-53rev5-AC-1
NIST-800-53rev5-IA-1
```

Comment: Good that you have added your efforts and sample of input, request you to kindly do add sample of output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: updated with desired output.

Comment: Could you please also mention which language it is?

Comment: I am writing a python script and `re` to do the regex matching. added in the description as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!NIST-Privacy-v1\.1)(?!NIST-CSF-v1\.1).*-.*-.*[.-].*$
```

Output:

```
AWS-CIS-v1.4-1.10
SOC-2-CC6.8
NIST-800-53rev5-CM-3(1)
NIST-800-53rev5-AU-12(4)
SOC-2-CC6.1
NISTPrivacyFramework-v1.0-PR.AC-P1
NIST-800-53rev5-AC-1
NIST-800-53rev5-IA-1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gM9e44/1

- `^` => Given pattern must start from the beginning of the line
- `[.-]` => "-" or "."
- `^(?!NIST-Privacy-v1\.1)` => It must not start with "NIST-Privacy-v1.1"
- `^(?!NIST-Privacy-v1\.1)(?!NIST-CSF-v1\.1)` => It must not start with "NIST-Privacy-v1.1" or "NIST-CSF-v1.1"
- `$` => Given pattern must finish at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks for that. I want to match everything except the two strings. All other strings should be returned as a match

Comment: @abhinavsingh I updated the answer to match the new desired output added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for your job:

```bash
^(?!NIST-(?:CSF|Privacy)-v1\.1$)(?:[^-]*-){2}.*[.-].*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/auxfAM/4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!NIST-(?:CSF|Privacy)-v1\.1,$)`: Negative lookahead to fail to match when input is `NIST-Privacy-v1.1` or `NIST-CSF-v1.1`
- `(?:[^-]*-){2}`: Match 0 or more of non-hyphen characters followed by a hyphen. Repeat this group 2 times
- `.*[.-]`: Match any text followed by dot or hyphen
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any text